# Add a table to an existing mysql replication?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, replication

I have an existing mysql replication set up (Windows 2008 to Ubuntu 9.04) and created several new tables in the master database. These are not showing up in the slave database.

Do new tables automatically get copied to the slave DB, or do I need to set up replication again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that other data is successfully replicating.

Replication in mysql is per-server, so the most likely problems are that either you aren't binloging the events, or that the slave is ignoring them.

For binglogs, verify you aren't turning sql_log_bin off for the connection (which would require SUPER) and that the various options [binary-log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html) options are set correctly. You can verify this by running `mysqlbinlog` on the server's binlogs.

On the slave side, check the [replication options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-rules.html).

Comment: Thanks - the slave server went down, and the slave wasn't matched up with the master.

Thanks for the quick reply.